# MYSQL: How to sort number DESC with plus value as high

Tags: mysql

I need some help to create desire output with pure MYSQL. My question is By fire SQL below:

```
SELECT
    r.questions_id
    ,r.Empty_Peg_Count AS 'Empty_Pegs'
FROM
    Training_Core.results AS r
ORDER BY
    CAST(r.Empty_Peg_Count AS SIGNED INTEGER) DESC;
```

I'm getting below output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [questions_id] => 256332653
            [Empty_Pegs] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [questions_id] => 256332653
            [Empty_Pegs] => 2+
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [questions_id] => 256332653
            [Empty_Pegs] => 1
        )
)
```

I want value with **+** sign as high priority and it should show first. my desired output is as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [questions_id] => 256332653
            [Empty_Pegs] => 2+
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [questions_id] => 256332653
            [Empty_Pegs] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [questions_id] => 256332653
            [Empty_Pegs] => 1
        )
)
```

Can anyone help me how to get this result with SQL query?

Thanks an advance!

Comment: What is the order of 2+,2,1+,1?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Value with sign + always returns after value without a sign.

Comment: Why don't you put some higher number (3 or 20 or anything else) instead of "2+" and order will be correct. And then replace that "3" with "2+" when you print your results...

Comment: @nl-x Type of Empty_Peg_Count is varchar so I have cascade to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second `order by` rule:

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(r.Empty_Peg_Count AS SIGNED INTEGER) DESC
    ,r.Empty_Peg_Count LIKE '%+%' DESC;
```

This will push the entries with a `+` to the top.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I want. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RIGHT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) to check if the last character is a `+` and use that as a secondary `ORDER BY` field:

```
SELECT
    r.questions_id
    ,r.Empty_Peg_Count AS 'Empty_Pegs'
FROM
    Training_Core.results AS r
ORDER BY
    CAST(r.Empty_Peg_Count AS SIGNED INTEGER) DESC
  , RIGHT(r.Empty_Peg_Count, 1) = '+' DESC
```

Comment: This working fine and its as per my need! Thanks, Nick!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply sort using the following

```
SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY
CASE 
   WHEN right(`Empty_Pegs`,1) = '+' THEN (left(`Empty_Pegs`,1)*10)
ELSE `Empty_Pegs`
END DESC;
```